# firebase asking for key id when activating for iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase

[image]

What does the key id mean? Please help me, I don't know what to enter in there.

Answer (score 24):

If you want Push notification using `FCM- Firebase Cloud messaging` you need to provide either `key` or `.p12` file. You can create in your developer account.[Visit this link](https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/).

Also, its not compulsory if you are using `firebase` as a only database purpose. If you want push notification or cloud message then you need to provide this `certificate` or `key` things.

In your developer account you have to follow below steps

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3**

[image]

**Step 4**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In your apple account go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section.You can see **Keys** section in left side category.

> Click Keys->All, Now you can see list of keys.

Click your key which you created for firebase APNS auth key.it will show prompt it shows Key ID:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have selected "APNS Auth key" option while uploading .p12 file **(Attached image (1)** ).
[image]
To generate a "APNS Auth key", You should open developer.apple.com, and generate key from below attached image.
[image]

If you don't have  "APNS Auth key", you should go with "APNs Certificate" option in firebase **(Attached image (2)**. In that case, Firebase will not ask you for "key id".

Comment: thanks a lot but I have tried to add the key witch you show. and after I insert and continue the response comes back to unknown error?